Как поменять цену товара в корзине битрикс 1с
Не могу разобраться- как поменять цену в корзине товара, на битрикс 1с. В компоненте sale.order.ajax - я меняю цену товаров в корзине. Но цена при этом не меняется в заказе. Как можно это реализовать. Буду рад любой помощи.
$arBasketItems = array();
$dbBasketItems = CSaleBasket::GetList(
        array(
                "NAME" => "ASC",
                "ID" => "ASC"
            ),
        array(
                "FUSER_ID" => CSaleBasket::GetBasketUserID(),
                "LID" => SITE_ID,
                "ORDER_ID" => "NULL"
            ),
        false,
        false,
        array("ID", "CALLBACK_FUNC", "MODULE", 
              "PRODUCT_ID", "QUANTITY", "DELAY", 
              "CAN_BUY", "PRICE", "WEIGHT")
    );
while ($arItems = $dbBasketItems->Fetch())
{
    if (strlen($arItems["CALLBACK_FUNC"]) > 0)
    {
        CSaleBasket::UpdatePrice($arItems["ID"], 
                                 $arItems["CALLBACK_FUNC"], 
                                 $arItems["MODULE"], 
                                 $arItems["PRODUCT_ID"], 
                                 $arItems["QUANTITY"]);
        $arItems = CSaleBasket::GetByID($arItems["ID"]);
    }
 $arFields = array(
                "PRICE" => 1500,
            );
 CSaleBasket::Update($arItems['ID'], $arFields);
    $arBasketItems[] = $arItems;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arBasketItems);
echo "</pre>";
}
?>


Сначала проверить, что функция отрабатывает.$result = CSaleBasket::Update($arItems['ID'], $arFields); if(!$result->isSuccess()){print_r($result->getErrors());}

Спасибо, но выходит ошибка связанная с этим isSuccess()

А, ну да, здесь напрямую ошибка не выдаётся... Нужно if(!result){print_r( $APPLICATION->GetException());}

@ВикторКарев, ошибку не выдает. В $arBasketItems- цена меняется, но как сделать, чтобы она формировалась и в заказе. Я просто перечитал документацию битрикс, но решения не нашел

Документация у Битрикс сильно отстаёт от разработки. Тут остаётся только анализировать исходники... https://bxapi.ru/src/?module_id=sale&name=CSaleBasket::Update

@ВикторКарев, Спасибо за помощь! С этой задачей я не справляюсь, поэтому мой заказчик в поисках другого разработчика, если вам интересна эта задача- можете скинуть свой ник в тг и я посоветую вас заказчику.
